# AdvancedFilter - filter a specific column with its value from another NOT adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

i already asked this question kind of on stackoverflow but i think i made myself indistinct. Below you can see the code. What I'm trying to do is to get the AdvancedFilter on Column C in addition to its pair in Column I and also just copy these unique values together to an adjacent range (A to C a new worksheet)

What i tried to do is to use `set` and declare "Discount" to a specific Range which gets filtered with `&` too. Important to know is that C:C gets splitted, so on the new sheet `dws` it needs column A and B,the variable `Discounts` therefore shall be in Cloumn C in `dws`.

```
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    **Set Discounts = ActiveSheet.Range("I:I")**
    
    sws.Range("C:C" **& Discounts**).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws, _
        Unique:=True

  dws.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Dim rng As Range:
    Set rng = dws.Range("A1:B1", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    rng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

What i would like to know is, if the `&` is the right approach and if its just a problem of the assigned Ranges itself or if is a general logic mistake.

**For example**

- Do i have to `set` first the whole range where the filter shall work in? Set Area = ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z")?
- Is the `union` method a better approach? (I already tried also this one)

*I have to write it as an Makro because the Sheet where the filter works on shall work by just one button whereby the sheet itself is always different.*

Comment: You can't apply an advanced filter to separate ranges, but you don't need to anyway. Just add the column headers you need to the output range and those are the only columns you will get in the result.

Comment: @Rory but within the Output Range i declare the range i would like to put the copied data dont i? Not the data i would like to copy? So If i can just filter one coulmns (here C:C) to get unique ..how does the system know that i would like to copy the filter on C:C and  additional to these unique values their value of column I:I ? So its just possible by filtering "C:I"? (but then it doesnt know that the filter for unique values has to be applied just on C:C

Comment: You can't do that, no. You'd need to filter in place, then copy column I - but if the combinations of I and C are not unique as well, are you not missing some I values out? For example, if you have 'a' three times in col C, and 1, 2 and 3 in col I for those rows, which col I value do you want?

Comment: @Rory if i get you right, you are right :) ...so i want to filter column C:C by using AdvancedFilter, exclude values in between column D:I and want to copy column C with column J. Therefore the values of J should be assigned to the prefiltered values of Column C:C, that should be possible or?

Comment: Yes, you filter the whole range C:J but only put the headers for C and J in the first row of the output range, and those are the only two columns that will be in the results.